# Efficient way to find all instances of Substring within a Swift String

Tags: swift, string, swift4, string-search

Swift 4 apparently has introduced a lot of new changes to String. I'm wondering if there is now a built-in method for finding all instances of a substring within a String.

Here's the kind of thing I'm looking for:

```
let searchSentence = "hello world, hello"
let wordToMatch = "hello"

let matchingIndexArray = searchSentence.indices(of: "wordToMatch")
```

'matchingIndexArray' would then be [0, 13]

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation

let searchSentence = "hello world, hello"

var searchRange = searchSentence.startIndex..<searchSentence.endIndex
var ranges: [Range<String.Index>] = []

let searchTerm = "hello"

while let range = searchSentence.range(of: searchTerm, range: searchRange) {
    ranges.append(range)
    searchRange = range.upperBound..<searchRange.upperBound
}

print(ranges.map { "(\(searchSentence.distance(from: searchSentence.startIndex, to: $0.lowerBound)), \(searchSentence.distance(from: searchSentence.startIndex, to: $0.upperBound)))" })
```

outputs:

```
["(0, 5)", "(13, 18)"]
```

Comment: @JoshCaswell Nope; tried it in CodeRunner before posting it. It works in Swift 4 as written, and provides the output listed.

Comment: @JoshCaswell It's been in there at least since Swift 3, I think. Could you please remove the downvote, if that's the reason you put it there?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Fair enough.

Comment: @JoshCaswell One reason that the built-in version of `range(of:)` is better than casting to `NSString` is because you get a native `Range` which is an optional, instead of a non-optional `NSRange` using the decidedly un-Swifty `NSNotFound` sentinel.

Comment: @JoshCaswell it has been available at least since Swift 2 but it used to be written as `rangeOfString`. After Swift 3 the syntax changed to `range(of: String)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer @CharlesSrstka. Your solution isn't quite right though– say we're searching for the word "do" and the sentence contains the word "dodo". What will happen?

Comment: @AdamBryant You'd get (0..<2) and (2..<4), of course, because those are the instances of the substring within the string. Your question did not ask to search by whole words.

Comment: Fair enough. I’ll post a different question and hopefully it will be better formulated. There is a very practical need in actual software for highly efficient word matching, and it is in no way clear in any of the documentation what the solution is in Swift.